# Is it possible for a vbScript to know which host it is running under?

Tags: vbscript, host

In my vbScript I would like to write to the command line or event log depending on how it is hosted (cScript or wScript).

If hosted under cScript, I branch to:

```
wScript.echo "useful message"
```

If hosted under wScript, I branch to:

```
wScript.shell.logEvent 4, "useful message"
```

I thought wScript.name might work, but it always returns "Windows Script Host".

```
wScript.echo "wScript.name=" & wScript.name & "."
```

Comment: I just found the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236849/vbscript-determine-which-function-is-running).